# Is it good or bad to creating a Kinesis on demand for cost optimisation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Here is the scenario:

I have an X number of producers which generates the millions scheduled notifications (mail, SMS and push notification) at a different time of the day and night.

I'm using the AWS Kinesis stream which collects all notification entries and using a triggered base lambda function (which mapped to the AWS Kinesis) to process those entries

**Problem**:

Need to keep a Kinesis Stream awake all the time

**Possible solution**:

Create a kinesis on demand.

For example. The producer will predict the load size and according to some predefined algo, a producer will create a Kinesis with X number of shards.

Once the job is done then do the cleanup.

Question is does the above approach looks good and cost-effective?
Is there any technical challenges or blockers

Comment: A single Kinesis shard costs under $0.40 per day. Unless you are using hundreds of shards, the cost to have a developer implement a scaling algorithm will far exceed the savings in shard-hours.

Comment: @kdgregory isn't it one time developer cost with some maintenance?

Comment: Only you know your numbers. If you have a large number of shards it may be worthwhile. But if you're dealing with "millions" of messages per day, you probably don't need a lot of shards to start with (consider: as long as your records are under 1k in length, and you use `PutRecords` rather than `PutRecord`, one shard can accept a million records in 30 minutes; 10 shards will take 3 minutes).